# Diffference between mingw32-make-bin and msys-make-bin in MINGW64

Tags: mingw, msys

If the question be relevant to StackOverflow, would someone be kind enough to tell the difference between the packages "mingw32-make-bin" and "msys-make-bin".

I believe them to be different packages because they are listed as different packages in the MinGW Installation Manager and I don't understand MinGW that well. Google searches and seeing the official documentation have been unfruitful as I could not understand that much:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MinGW FAQ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ) says:

> **What's the difference between make and mingw32-make?**
>
> The "native" (i.e.: MSVCRT dependent) port of make is lacking in some functionality and has modified functionality due to the lack of POSIX on Win32. There also exists a version of make in the MSYS distribution that is dependent on the MSYS runtime. This port operates more as make was intended to operate and gives less headaches during execution. Based on this, the MinGW developers/maintainers/packagers decided it would be best to rename the native version so that both the "native" version and the MSYS version could be present at the same time without file name collision.

[CMake documentation on MinGW Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html) says:

> Use this generator under a Windows command prompt with MinGW in the PATH and using mingw32-make as the build tool. The generated makefiles use cmd.exe as the shell to launch build rules. They are not compatible with MSYS or a unix shell.

Practically speaking, msys/make (along with the rest of MSYS or MSYS2) is usually the one that can handle cross-platform Makefiles (often created by `./configure` created in turn by autotools).  mingw32-make is the one that doesn't need the whole of MSYS or MSYS2 to work, but it can only handle Windows-specific Makefiles (or ones that are carefully crafted to work with both Make versions.

Comment: It's not that the format of the Makefile is different per se, but some aspects of mingw32-make may behave differently, for supporting backslash as path seperator instead of slash. I also noticed -pipe doesn't work well with mingw32-make.

Comment: As you say, it's not the format, it's the contents.